# Do not allow to push empty or undefined string respectively into my array

Tags: javascript

Despite I added the condition in my if query that inputs value should not be undefined, when i click on the add button when there is no input or only white space created with the space bar a empty string is pushed into my array and will be displayed from my arrays length counter. How can this be possible even though a empty string like "" or "   " is undefined? How can I implement my desired function?

```
<input>
<button id="add">add</button>
<button id="remove">remove</button>
    <p></p>
    <span>0</span>
```

```
window.onload = function () {
  const inp = document.querySelector("input");
  const btn = document.getElementById("add");
  const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
  const rBtn = document.getElementById("remove");
  const p = document.querySelector("p");
  const sp = document.querySelector("span");
  let toDo = [];

  addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (inp.value != undefined) {
      console.log(inp.value)
      toDo.push(inp.value);
      sp.innerHTML = toDo.length;
    }
    p.innerHTML = toDo.join(" ");
    inp.value = "";
    inp.value = "";
  });

  rBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    inp.value = "";
    p.innerHTML = "";
    toDo = [];
    sp.innerHTML = "0";
    console.clear()
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `input` is `empty` this doesn't mean it's value equal to `undefined`, you need to `trim()` the value and check if the `length` is not equal to `zero`, with that if the input value is empty or just white spaces, it will not be pushed in the array.

```
    if (inp.value.trim().length !== 0) {
      console.log(inp.value)
      toDo.push(inp.value);
      sp.innerHTML = toDo.length;
    }
```